# How to make my new theme read [youtube id="id of the video here" width="600" height="350"]?

Tags: embed, youtube

I recently changed the theme on my website, and now all my videos, which were used on the posts with this format:

> [youtube id="only the id here" width="600" height="350"]

are not understood, and inside the posts like [this one](http://pocketlife.com.br/2014/03/cut-the-rope-2-chega-finalmente-ao-android/).

The following message is shown where the video is supposed to be:

`Please enter the url to a YouTube video.`

How can I make it so I don't need to go into all the posts I have that has any video inside and edit in a way that WordPress will embed it?

Comment: Why not just use the built-in youtube embedding instead of using a custom shortcode? See [Embeds](https://codex.wordpress.org/Embeds).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can for example:

- Copy the YouTube shortcode from the old theme to your new theme.

  Locate the line (most likely in the `functions.php` file):

  ```
  add_shortcode( 'youtube', 'some_function' );
  ```

  and copy this line and the `some_function()` to your `functions.php` in your new
  theme or better yet - create a new plugin file including:

  ```
  /*Plugin Name: YouTube embed shortcode from old theme */

  add_shortcode( 'youtube', 'some_function' );

  some_function( $args = array(), $content = ''){ /* ...code... */}
  ```
- Add a YouTube embed plugin with the same parameters.
- Create your own plugin to handle this.

  Here's a poor man's version (untested):

  ```
  /*Plugin Name: YouTube embed shortcode - poor man's version */

  add_shortcode( 'youtube', 'ytb_sc' );

  if( ! function_exists( 'ytb_sc' ) ):

      function ytb_sc( $atts = array(), $content = '' )
      {
         $atts = shortcode_atts( array(
             'id'      => '',             // default id
             'width'   => 640,            // default width (px)
             'height'  => 480,            // default height (px)
         ), $atts, 'ytb_sc' );

           // Sanitize input:
           $id      = esc_attr( $atts['id'] );
           $width   = (int) $atts['width'];
           $height  = (int) $atts['height'];

          if( ! empty( $id ) ) {
              $sc = sprintf( '[embed width="%d" height="%d"]%s%s[/embed]',
                             $width,
                             $height,
                             'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=',
                             $id );
          } else {
              return __( 'Missing YouTube ID!' );
          }

          // Output
          return $GLOBALS['wp_embed']->run_shortcode($sc);
      }

  endif;
  ```

Hope this helps!

Comment: unfortunately it didn't work =[ ... I think my theme (Explicit) has some code blocking any kind of change to it's natural settings for youtube for some reason. It's even blocking the plugin jetpack from working. I'll just have to change it one by one! =/ Thanks a lot for your answer!

Comment: ok, what method did you try?

Comment: oh and this is the code i found on functions.php on my old theme (LeetPress) 

add_shortcode('youtube', 'shortcode_youtube');
 function shortcode_youtube($atts) {
  $atts = shortcode_atts(
   array(
    'id' => '',
    'width' => 600,
    'height' => 360
   ), $atts);
  
   return '<div class="video-shortcode"><iframe title="YouTube video player" width="' . $atts['width'] . '" height="' . $atts['height'] . '" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/' . $atts['id'] . '" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe></div>';
 }

Comment: I tried creating a plugin with the code you gave me, tried to create a plugin with the code of my old theme, tried installing TinyMCE, hmmm and installing many other plugins for youtube embed

Comment: my website keeps on showing the message "Please enter the url to a YouTube video." where the videos should be. =[

Comment: I'm just curious, what happens if you name your shortcode to something else than `[youtube]`, for example `[ytb]`. Does such a shortcode work in your theme, with the above suggestions? I mean can you post a demo post with different shortcode name? If that's possible, then you could replace `[youtube` with `[ytb` via single SQL query (taking backup first).

Comment: it does not =[ ... I tried changing a post to `[ytb]` but it just shows up as a normal phrase. Strange thing is it does understand the begining of the shortcode `[youtube]` but doesn't understand the rest of it. It surely begins with this code but not on the same format, and I can't find it on functions.php or css.php the correct way it would read.

Comment: I found the code lines for the youtube shortcode but it's too long to send here

Comment: hmmm it understand this [youtube url="rm81d05QAzQ"] , so in theory if I changed all "id" for "url" it would work... but I have no idea how to do that hahahaha... maybe it's better to just embed the original code from youtube and change all of the posts one by one, so it doens't cause me even more problems on the future right?

Comment: Then you could for example try to replace the string `[youtube id=` with `[youtube url=` in the `post_content` field. You can do that with many available tools like [this one](http://wordpress.org/plugins/find-replace/screenshots/) or [this one](https://interconnectit.com/products/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/) (remember to backup before testing). In general I like to use the native `[embed]` shortcode.

Comment: yeah but when it is set to `[youtube url=` it doesn't allow fullscreen, so it doesn't work for me unfortunatelly =/ ... I'll just change it manually to the native youtube shortcode so I don't have future similar problems. Thanks a lot for you help @birgire !

Comment: ok good luck with that ;-)